# Getting "Could not find curses error" while installing mariadb from mariadbserver in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, libraries, cmake, mariadb

I am installing MariaDB in my ubuntu based on the following [readme](https://github.com/AgeDB-Enterprise/maria-server#readme) file.

My ubuntu version is 22.04 and I am using the MariaDB branch 11.0.
I have followed the starting the steps and they are running perfectly fine.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list
```

After that I put the contents in the contents in this file and run the following commands which executed perfectly fine.

```
  sudo apt-get install software-properties-common \
  devscripts \
  equivs \
  curl \
  git
  sudo apt-get build-dep mariadb-server
```

After that I run those commands and that run also fine.

```
sudo curl -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc 
'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc'
sudo apt-get update
```

Then came the Build part

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/{your-username}/maria-server
mkdir ~/maria-server-build
mkdir ~/maria-server-data
cd ~/maria-server-build
```

After that when I run this command then it is giving me an error.

```
cmake ~/maria-server/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

The error is as follows:

```
-- Wsrep-lib version: 1.0.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find Curses (missing: CURSES_LIBRARY CURSES_INCLUDE_PATH)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindCurses.cmake:268 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
cmake/readline.cmake:55 (FIND_PACKAGE)
cmake/readline.cmake:185 (FIND_CURSES)
CMakeLists.txt:389 (MYSQL_CHECK_READLINE)
```

I don't get it if any package is missing or something.

**UPDATE:**
I have now installed some missing packages through this command.

```
sudo apt install libncurses-dev
```

But now I am getting a little different errors.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake- 
3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find GnuTLS (missing: GNUTLS_LIBRARY GNUTLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
(Required is at least version "3.3.24")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindGnuTLS.cmake:68 
(FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
libmariadb/CMakeLists.txt:336 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this build in particular, but generally it would indicate a missing `libncurses-dev` package

Comment: Can you tell me the command by which this can be resolved

Comment: `sudo apt install libncurses-dev`

Comment: I have tried this command too, but still getting errors

Comment: Are you still getting *the same* errors, or different ones?

Comment: The errors are a little different now and I have added that in the question

Comment: so you probably need to install the GNU TLS development package (libgnutls28-dev) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors were changed when I used this command.

```
sudo apt install libncurses-dev
```

The errors which come when I change this command are as follows:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake- 
3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find GnuTLS (missing: GNUTLS_LIBRARY GNUTLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
(Required is at least version "3.3.24")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindGnuTLS.cmake:68 
(FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
libmariadb/CMakeLists.txt:336 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

So, when I used this command this error has been resolved

```
sudo apt-get install gnutls-dev
```

After that, I was getting errors related to bison. So, I installed the bison at the end and the error has been resolved.

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison
```

After that error has been resolved and I build the MariaDB successfully using this command.

```
cmake ~/maria-server/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```